# How to implement blocks of template literals in the same module?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

Consider a `module.exports` template that contains a `HTML` code. This module takes two parameters of data. This is an example of the code:

```
module.exports = (data, d) => {
  return `
    <div class='modal-dialog modal-md' role='document'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <h3 class='text-center'>${d.nombre}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        ${data.map((t) => {
          return `
            <div class='thumbnail'>
            </div>
          `;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  `
}
```

I am using two different blocks of template literals, one for `d` dataset, and a second one for `data` parameter which needs a `map` method in order to get data.

However, when data have two or more items in `array` I got a kind of `,` between each `div`.

I got this output:

[image]

I tried to use `yo-yo` module and write in a different file the `map` method, but I didn't get a different result.

Using two blocks of template literals is a good practice or am I missing something that could avoid this output?

Comment: I got a `comma`, like the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` method returns an array, and as you embed its result in a template string, that array is implicitly converted to a string, which by default adds commas between array elements.

Solution: chain a `.join('')`:

```
    ${data.map((t) => {
      return `
        <div class='thumbnail'>
        </div>
      `;
    }).join('')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using template literals, your array is being coerced into a string after your map (you're not using jsx). See what happens when toString is called on array (it joins with a comma):

```js
console.log( [1,2].toString() );
```

To stop this behavior in your particular case, call `.join()` on the array after the map:

```
${
    data.map((t) => `<div class='thumbnail'></div>`)
    .join('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand why. Thanks for the example.